# Need to center placeholder text in custom UITextField vertically in iOS

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I am working on an iOS application where I have subclassed my UITextField in order to set the colour of my placeholder text.  I have also centered it horizontally, but my problem is that my placeholder text is not centered vertically, and for some reason, the cursor is not centered within the placeholder text, but instead appears just after the very first character of the placeholder text.

My method in my subclass of UITextField which I override in order to set the colour of the placeholder text and center the text horizontally looks like this:

```
- (void)drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Set colour and font size of placeholder text
    [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
    [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:28] lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeMiddleTruncation alignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

}
```

Here is my code where I create and set up my UITextField:

```
_field = [[CustomTextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(190, 300, 644, 64)];
_field.delegate = (id)self;
[_field becomeFirstResponder];
[_field setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
[_field setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[_field setPlaceholder:@"Enter First and Last Name"];
[[_field layer] setMasksToBounds:8.0f];
[[_field layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
[[_field layer] setBorderWidth:1.0f];
[_field setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:25]];
[_field setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
[_field setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
_field.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
[self.view addSubview:_field];
```

I initially subclassed my UITextField because while everything looked fine, my placeholder text for some reason was grey instead of white (which I set as the text colour for the textfield).  Ironically, the placeholder text was centered both vertically AND horizontally, AND the cursor was centered.  So in order to correct the placeholder text colour, I subclass the UITextField, only to open up more problems now.

Is there a way that I can now center the placeholder text vertically, as well as have the cursor centered as well?  Better still, is there a way for me to change the grey colour of the placeholder text to white without having to subclass it?  This would be ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you forgot to implement  in .h ( not in your custom TextField class )

```
@interface YourView : UIView<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

and the delegate method didn't called ! The placeholder textcolor must be that color what you want, if you do it like this.

```
#import "YourView.h"

@implementation YourView

// .....

_field.delegate = self;
_field.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
// ....
```

You can add some vertical padding like this:

```
UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 30)];
_field.leftView = paddingView;
_field.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

from apple developer library:

> leftView
> The overlay view displayed on the left side of the text
> field.
>
> @property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *leftView
>
> Discussion You can use
> the left overlay view to indicate the intended behavior of the text
> field. For example, you might display a magnifying glass in this
> location to indicate that the text field is a search field.
>
> The left overlay view is placed in the rectangle returned by the
> leftViewRectForBounds: method of the receiver. The image associated
> with this property should fit the given rectangle. If it does not fit,
> it is scaled to fit.
>
> If your overlay view does not overlap any other sibling views, it
> receives touch events like any other view. If you specify a control
> for your view, the control tracks and sends actions as usual. If an
> overlay view overlaps the clear button, however, the clear button
> always takes precedence in receiving events.

[link to apple developer library / UITextField](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/leftView)

I hope this helps !